Print tree of uninstalled dependencies and their filesizes for apt packages
I sometimes try to install a program using apt, and it turns out the download size is much bigger than I expected. I then want to know: which dependencies are so big?
Is there an existing command which does the same as tree -d -h /path, but for the tree of uninstalled dependencies and their sizes of a not-yet-installed package that we want to install with apt?
I.e. if we run sudo apt install mypackage and are surprised to see it takes 20GB of space, we would instead run something like dep-tree mypackage and it should print something like this:
[2KB]  mypackage
├── [5KB]  some-dependency
│   └── [20GB]  insanely-large-dependency
│       ├── [5MB]  some-library
│       └── [2KB]  some-other-library
├── [2MB]  some-minor-package
│   ├── [5KB]  whatever-package
│   └── [9KB]  whatever2-package

Does such a command exist? If not how can we do this I cannot be the only one who needs this. (It probably should be part of apt by default, but whatever).
There is a similar question here, but the answers only print the size of an individual package, or of the total of dependencies, they don't print a tree which shows the size of each of them.

This question is similar to: How to determine the size of a package while using apt prior to downloading?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@graham, edited at the end.

@kos, is it correct that this only prints it once you've installed the package? My question is about the size before you've installed it. And also, it should ONLY list the dependencies that we haven't installed yet.

@kos, strange. When I run your line and replacing package_name with emacs, I get E: No packages found
:
E: No packages found
:

Now it generates
emacs-gtk: 7.9M emacs-pgtk: 7.8M emacs-lucid: 7.9M emacs-nox: 7.4M
i.e. total about 30MB. But sudo apt install emacs --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests says it needs to add about 200MB

Fair enough, the command will only list the first "level" of dependencies, it should be run recursively to print everything; useless to your case then. It should be made into a script to address this as well. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of something that will do exactly what you want, so perhaps a script will be the only way anyways.

"they don't print a tree which shows the size of each of them" why is that so important to you in this context? If you need a graphical representation (for whatever purpose) is it not possible to structure some template (as in you example in the question) and then fill in the blanks as it were? How often will this be a requirement in any event and will it be worth the investment in the final analysis. You'll have the facts at your disposal in any event. Not intended to be obtuse - just curious.

@graham, the main reason is that I want to know which subpackages are how big and which depends on which. the existing methods all seem to just print one package, or the total size. Printing it as a tree as opposed to a list of lists is just because it is easier to read, not essential. I'm not at all sure what you mean by this template idea.

@graham, basically I want to be able to clearly see "ah it depends on this package which depends on gcc which is XXMB, THAT's why its so big, that makes sense". I honestly don't really get why apt doesn't print that by default.

"...by this template idea" just my programming background kicking in. I'd consider getting the raw data, pulling it in programmatically to an application which would parse the data to present it in a graphical format of my choosing and construction. Simply that (if it makes sense).

This resembles a debate that was settled over 25 years ago. One of the original design goals of apt was to stop forcing humans to pay attention to dependency trees. Apt is supposed to do it all for you, like a good computer should. Your curiosity is laudable, I went through that phase too, but apt is the wrong tool to satisfy it.

@user535733, I don't really wanna "think" about dependency trees, I just want to know why a package is so big, so I can maybe pick a smaller subset, or whatever.

Not quite a tree, but I suppose it can be close enough:
aptitude install --visual-preview <package>

For installing vim-nox on an Ubuntu 24.04 Docker container, this looks like:

Like I said, it's not quite a tree, but the package description in the bottom half which packages required the selected package.

It's better than nothing, thanks
